# How to make file association (not with CLI tool/command)?

Tags: nautilus, 11.10

In Ubuntu 11.04 when I right click on a file in Nautilus and chose "open with" I could select application and tick on check box to make it default application for certain file type

In 11.10 there is no such option, so I'm wondering what's alternative to it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Right click the file and select open with. Or right click and select properties, open with and select the application you want to associate with.

Comment: So they removed option to make default application in Properties. Thanks

Comment: No, it's still there.

Comment: Where exactly? There is no option to make default application with "open with" dialog on my PC

Comment: It is in the same place. You no longer select a radio button. You select the application and press "Set as default" (I don't use English Ubuntu so it may be different). You can add applications to be shown in the list.

Comment: No, it's not. There is no such button. Can you show screen-shot? And when you select application from "open with > other applications" it will *not* make it default application for current file type

Comment: http://ubuntuone.com/6TwedbCE430huBNB1HFExr

Comment: Well, you are perhaps showing me Properties dialog and I already thanked you for that. Aren't we talking about context menu: "Open with" dialog? About missing feature in that "Open with" dialog, that was present in 11.04 and missing in 11.10?

Comment: Is this what you're talking about? http://ubuntuone.com/76kUzfdRu8uFwOFyn7Xcr0

Comment: Yes. Option to make default application was removed from that dialog. It was present in 11.04

Comment: Where? http://ubuntuone.com/3Hypyzx0xqEhWhIXkXe9Pw

Comment: :D Please articulate a bit more words so we can understand each other. I'll assume that you are showing me screenshot from Natty, and asking where can you set default program. - Just open that dialog and you'll have a chance to tick box default program

Comment: yes, but I've already told you that. You no longer check a checkbox. You select an application and click "Select" or "Choose".

Answer (score 1):

right click on the file. 
select "properties". 
click tab "open with".
there you have the button "set as default".

it took a while to figure it out, I think it was more intuitive in natty, but there you have it anyway.