# Why can't I make a file association in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, mime-type

After upgrading to 11.10, the association I had created to open SGF files with an application called quarry is lost.

If I select Right-button->Properties->Open With... on an SGF file, quarry is not listed, but it appears in the Right-button->Open With... menu.

What's going on here?

By the way, i tried "mimeopen whatever.sgf" and it works. So mime-types associations are ok,  but something is broken in nautilus it seems... For example:

% mimeopen  Kogo.sgf

Please choose a default application for files of type application/x-go-sgf

```
1) Quarry  (quarry)
2) notepad  (wine-extension-txt)
3) GVim Text Editor  (gvim)
4) gedit  (gedit)
5) AbiWord  (abiword)
6) Other...
```

As you can see, Quarry is properly detected. But in the Properties->Open With dialog in Nautilus, Quarry is not availaible. And because in 11.10 Nautilus doesn't longer provides the option to add a custom command to open an application, i have no way to add a file association.

Comment: I think your problem is same as mine asked here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61744/how-to-make-file-association-not-with-cli-tool-command, basically you'll have to use Properties and make association from there

Comment: I will do but, when making a new association, the app I want to use(quarry) is not listed. And because they removed custom commands Gnome3, i cannot add it :(.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Nautilus not allowing me to set acroread as
the default for pdf files.  Perhaps you can use something like I did
to fix things up.  Like you, mimeopen worked fine.

xdg-mime query default application/pdf         # show current association

xdg-mime default /usr/share/applications/acroread.desktop application/pdf

This also made firefox open my pdf links with acroread, which was my real goal,
because the default evince "Document Viewer" doesn't open up tab panes and opening
up 10+ separate viewers with the Unity desktop is r-e-a-l-l-y painful.

Maybe a similar use of xdg-mime can fix your setup too?

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution: You can use PCManFM to add file associations, and these are then shown in Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use a GUI to set mime types ubuntu-tweak Admins tab, File Type Manager will do the job for you. The ap is available from http://ubuntu-tweak.com where you can download the deb file. Once downloaded you click the deb file and the Software Center will install it in the normal fashion. That is how I handled the situation and Nautilus then handled things in the fashion you expect.