# Setting custom commands for eBooks

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, ebooks, calibre

I wanted to follow these instructions from another thread about reading eBooks:

If you install `calibre`, and you just want to read a `mobi` file, then you can use the ebook-reader application that installed as part of the calibre package. To do this:

1. Right click on the mobi file and choose "Open with other application ..."
2. expand the arrow near the bottom that says "Use a custom command"
3. in the text box that appears, type "/usr/bin/ebook-reader"
4. tick the box that says "Remember this application for "Mobipocket e-book" files
5. click on the "Open" button

Unfortunately, that feature has disappeared/isn't available in my Ubuntu 11.10 standard install. Please can someone help me with a Terminal command-line for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61744/how-to-make-file-association-not-with-cli-tool-command

Comment: not a duplicate.

Comment: I want to use a CUSTOM COMMAND, and set the default ebook opening with the reader included with Calibre

Comment: I was under impression that you are looking for "Open with other application ..." action, which was moved to other place as explained in linked question

Comment: application doesn't appear in list of apps, so I'm stuck...

Comment: I'd like to set the ebook reader included in the Calibre software package as the default open software for mobi andother ebooks.

Unfortunately even though Calibre is installed, the ebook reader application doesn't appear in the apps list as far as I can tell

Comment: It should appear as "E-book Viewer" in application list, canonically. I would suggest you to also try FBReader if you can, as Calibre is one of the slowest application I've ever run, including their reader

Comment: thx, is there a quick simple way of installing FBReader?
Also, how do I fix the filetype not being recognized (mime?)

Comment: I'm not sure about your question, but you can install 'fbreader' with your package manager (i.e. search for `fbreader` with Software Centre). It handles .mobi format just fine here

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 3):

How about doing this in a terminal:

```
mimeopen -d filename.mobi
```

then select `Other...` from the menu.

Comment: and then what do you do for open it with ebook reader ?